# How to display thick line under header of sub menu using css

Tags: css

It took so much of time to add thick line under the headers of sub menus when hover(Business Units and Investor Relation) but still does not work. How to do that?

my code :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
     <li id="businessU">
     <a href="#">Business Units  </a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Engineering">Solution  Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Bioforce">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Biogen">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/AC">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="#">Solution E&E Technology Sdn Bhd</a> </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="Investor">
     <a href="#">Investor Relations</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu2">

     <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>

   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav.navbar-nav a:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: solid 2px transparent;
}

.nav.navbar-nav a:not(:last-child):hover {
    border-bottom: solid 2px red;
}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, but the problem is that the border-bottom line width is bigger than the sub menu width ?

Comment: Wouldn't that look odd? You can just style the ul or the li instead like this - http://www.bootply.com/VX4c5mR56y